# SQL Query to find data in table with different values

Tags: sql-server

trying to get distinct value from table where another field = to one id and not another.

```
select id from tbl1
where route = 28 but not = 30
```

the id has multiple entries and I am trying to find is id's that only have route 28 and no route 30. Below is what I tried without success:

```
select ID
FROM Table
Where route like '28' and route <> '30'
```

Comment: When you say route=28, it is by default not equal to 30. No?

Comment: The ID receives data from 2 sources, 28 is one route and 30 is another route. Even if I query = 28, that same ID may have an entry from 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.route = 28
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
     and  t2.route = 30
)
```

This approach is better if the condition gets more complicated or you want all columns.

Comment: Table t2, do I have to create? or is that a self join? Sorry, still learning.

Comment: @Zman: It's just a table alias. The `NOT EXISTS` is a correlated subquery with refers to the outer query via `id`. To differentiate between both i have used `t1` and `t2` as table alias for the table `Table`. In words: give me all records where route=28 and no other row exists with the same id but route=30.

Comment: Here is the actual query, I am still not having any luck:

Comment: select dbo.hex2int(SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,7,4))as MTU, 
 SignalDate_prm,  
 dbo.hex2int(SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,19,2)) as Signal_Level_ID,
 dbo.hex2int(SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,18,1)) as Signal
FROM mcm.dbo.TestTableSig
Where SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,6,1) = '0' and
SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,19,2) = '28' and Not exists
(select dbo.hex2int(SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,7,4))as MTU
from mcm.dbo.TestTableSig
where SUBSTRING(signalstirng_prm,19,2) = '30' )

Comment: @Zman: what is the error you get? You don't need to select anything in an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, it's just there to return a `bool`(as the name EXISTS suggests). So you can use `... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   mcm.dbo.testtablesig 
                       WHERE  Substring(signalstirng_prm, 19, 2) = '30')`. So it doesn't matter what you select in an `EXISTS`, it could also be `NULL`.

Comment: What is the id-column in your query? You have not linked the main query with the sub-query as i've done via `id`-column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
from tbl1 
group by id
having sum(case when route = 28 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when route = 30 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Oops, did not notice your answer. Deleting mine now.